# Optimize the way to get the previous and next record

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-mvc

Optimize the way to get the previous and next record.

I made an implementation with which I get the previous record and the next, but not very efficient. As we enter the log detail screen, in this case one player, the whole search of all records to check only the next and the previous is done.

In this case the search is only for equipment, but can be the case in detail is reached through a search engine with a filter where paged results are obtained. How I can improve implementation for the previous and next record?
What I want is not to have to retrieve all records, only the records you need.
This is my implementation:

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerService pService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/players/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final ModelAndView printPlayerDetail(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id, Locale locale) throws ControllerException 
    {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("players/detail");
        Player p = null;
        NavigatorDTO navigator = new NavigatorDTO();
        try {
            p = pService.getById(id);
            navigator.setId(p.getId());
            navigator.setRecords(pService.getNavigator(p.getTeam().getId()));
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            throw new ControllerException(this.messages.getMessage(ERROR_QUERY, null, locale), e);
        }
        PlayerDTO dto = new PlayerDTO();        
        dto.setId(p.getId());
        dto.setName(p.getName());
        if (p.getTeam() != null) {
            dto.setTeam(p.getTeam().getId());
        }           

        view.addObject("navigator", navigator);
        view.addObject("player", dto);
        return view;
    }   
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements PlayerService {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerDao pDao; 

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Integer> getNavigator(Integer teamId) throws ServiceException {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        try {
            List<Player> players = pDao.findByTeanm(teamId);
            for (Player p : players) {
                result.add(p.getId());
            }
        } catch (FacadeException e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

My Navigation Class:

```
public final class NavigatorDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;

    private List<Integer> records = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Integer> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(final List<Integer> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }   

    /**
     * Get next id
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getNext() {
        if ( id!=null ) {
            Integer actualPosition = records.indexOf(id);
            try {
                return records.get(actualPosition + 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }   
        } else { 
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get previous id
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getPrevious() {
        if (id != null){
            Integer actualPosition = records.indexOf(id);
            try {
                return records.get(actualPosition - 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get first id
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getFirst(){
        if (id != null) {
            try {
                return records.get(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get last id
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getLast(){
        if (id != null) {
            try{
                return records.get(records.size() - 1);
            } catch (Exception e){
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get total records
     * @return Total
     */
    public int getTotalrecords(){
        return (records == null) ? 1 : records.size();
    }

    /**
     * Get actual position
     * @return
     */
    public int getActualPosition(){
        return (records == null) ? 1 : records.indexOf(id) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your exact problem. What's the main problem, where's the issue? Which is the relevant code to look at? What kind of *records* are you talking about?

Comment: 5000-10000 records. What I want is to find a more efficient way without having to obtain all records of the table.It is supposed to get the detail of a player from a paged search players. If to go into detail I have to do a full search could be very heavy and inefficient.

Comment: Where do you get *all record of the table*? We cannot see that in the code. And if you already do that, then store the results in memory like in a cache so you will do future lookups against the cache rather than against the database, and this will highly speed up your performance. But then again, I don't understand what are you exactly doing and how this code relates to your problem. I cannot see any query being executed that will return that data.

Comment: My problem was not wanting to do a search, for example imagine that change the "findByTeam" for "getAll" or "find (Filter filter)". Thus a rather large list would recover. Just wanted to know how to get the next and previous track knowing his id, consultations to do so. In the post code I present my method, I do not put queries because in this case it is very obvious what they do. Two queries (one that brings a result and one that brings a list of results). I wanted to change the method to make 3 queries for example to get the current resistro, the next and previous if available.

Comment: Uh... your problem is rather confusing. The only way to know which records are *next* and *previous* is by retrieving an id or another way to identify them when you retrieve the data for the current record. Keep in mind that if you're using numeric ids this may be a simple as `id-1` and `id+1` or may not because that id may have been deleted from your data source. I still don't see a performance problem with this code. And again, if your concern is performance for data retrieval, use cache.

Comment: Ok, I'll do tests cache or can even make the query and instead of recovering an entity, in this case "player", retrieve a list of ids and so be faster and do not hibernate mapping class, thereby also saving me the code loop through the list.

Answer (score 1):

OFFSET pagination which is probably what you are doing is inherently slow.

See http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Unfortunately JPA doesn't really support keyset paging (I think). So you will have to use raw SQL.